# Finding Maximum Root

Tags: equation-solving

How can I find the greatest root for a polynomial if the polynomial degree is very large.
One way is using `NSolve`. This command can find all roots in numeric. Then, to find maximum root one can be use the command `Max`. This takes very long time for my calculation. Is there any short way to find max. root?

P.S: i am looking for the roots only real
Thanks...

Comment: "Greatest" as in "greatest in magnitude"? Are the roots of your polynomial all real, or can there be complex roots?

Comment: i am looking for the roots only real